# WP Query inside taxonomy.php kills the standard loop

Tags: loops, wordpress

I have made a custom taxonomy archive page called taxonomy-country.php. The file runs perfectly and loops through the current country and displays the posts within it.

Above this loop on the same templeate I want to display a map of all the post locations using Advanced Custom Fields. I've used the code before with no problems but not in an archive file, however when used at the top of the template the map and markers show fine but the standard archive loop no longer displays.

What is wrong with the wpquery that it kills the loop after it? Or is there another reason I can't run he query above the normal loop on an archive page?

```
<?php               
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'home',
'order'                  => 'ASC',
'orderby'                => 'title',
'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div class="acf-map">
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    $location = get_field('location');
    if( !empty($location) ):
    ?>
    <div class="acf-map">
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
            <h2 class="name"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <strong class="number"><?php echo do_shortcode('[mrp_rating_result rating_form_id="2"]'); ?></strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>         
<?php   }
} else {
// no posts found
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Just found out this should be shorter alternative:

```
wp_reset_postdata()
```

ORIGIONAL:

This line killed it:

```
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_query() ?
```

Reason: You did not use main $wp_query, hence $query->the_post() did not interfere with the current index of $wp_query. Resetting it will cause the main loop to restart.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

A safer way is to:

Before the category loop:

```
global $post;
$temp_post = $post;
```

After the category loop:

```
$post = $temp_post;
```

Just 3 lines and it should work.

Cheers!

Comment: No, still no output. I understand where you're coming from though, thanks

Comment: @user2272355 Updated my answer. And I don't think where I come from affects my "helping for free".

Answer (score 0):

As per above answer you have to store the **$post** in in temporary  variable and restore it before **wp_reset_query()**

example function code look like below

```
 function cd_meta_box_cb_hotel( $post )
    {
        global $post;
    $temp_post = $post;

        $selected=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hotel_location_id',true);
        $mquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'custom posttype',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,

    ));


    while ($mquery->have_posts()) {
        $mquery->the_post();



      // doing what you need


    }

    **$post = $temp_post;
    wp_reset_query();**


    }
```